# How decrease logical reads while getting result from view?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a view which I will mention its code below, when I filter entire code, I get proper logical reads, but when I filter the view, logical reads increases so much!

I used subquery instead of cte, I made so many changes in my code, but I couldn't get proper result

This is my view code:

```
create view att.view_notRule
as

with timeline
as
(
    select person,location,dateTime,d_base
    from att.view_pD1

    union all

    select person,location,dateTime_in,d_base
    from att.view_rule

    union all

    select person,location,dateTime_out,d_base
    from att.view_rule
),
timelineRanking
as
(
    select person,location,row_number() over (partition by person,location,d_base order by dateTime) rank,dateTime,d_base
    from timeline
)

select x.person,x.location,x.dateTime dateTime_start,y.dateTime dateTime_end,x.d_base
from timelineRanking x
inner join timelineRanking y on x.person=y.person and x.location=y.location and x.d_base=y.d_base
where x.rank+1=y.rank and x.rank%2=1
```

when I execute this query I face so many logical reads:

```
select *
from att.view_notRule
where person='B18FE132-2779-4E0D-A776-4BD27E7EEB7C'
```

But, when I filter person, inside the code, I get proper logical reads

I need to execute this:

```
select *
from att.view_notRule
where person='B18FE132-2779-4E0D-A776-4BD27E7EEB7C'
```

But getting proper logical reads

Answer (score 1):

When you are querying from a view that can't propagate predicates down to the base tables (which sometimes is due to the view design, and sometimes due to limitations in the query optimizer), a useful pattern is to replace the view with a In-Line Table-Valued Function, which is kind of like a parameterized view.

eg:

```
create or alter function att.view_notRule(@person varchar(200)) returns table 
as return

with timeline
as
(
    select person,location,dateTime,d_base
    from att.view_pD1
    where person = @person 

    union all

    select person,location,dateTime_in,d_base
    from att.view_rule
    where person = @person 

    union all

    select person,location,dateTime_out,d_base
    from att.view_rule
    where person = @person 

),
timelineRanking
as
(
    select person,location,row_number() over (partition by person,location,d_base order by dateTime) rank,dateTime,d_base
    from timeline
)

select x.person,x.location,x.dateTime dateTime_start,y.dateTime dateTime_end,x.d_base
from timelineRanking x
inner join timelineRanking y on x.person=y.person and x.location=y.location and x.d_base=y.d_base
where x.rank+1=y.rank and x.rank%2=1
```

Then if you need to run the view across multiple people, you can do so with CROSS APPLY.  But for your

Comment: Thanks for your respond, but I have a problem with this solution, it may user wants to use this table function with more filters,maybe just wants to filter person, maybe just person and location or maybe person, location, dateTime_start and dateTime_end or ....
with function table I will take these advantages from my user! I searched a bit and I couldn't find any way for this problem too.

Comment: Try it.  The query optimizer understands inline table-valued functions and can apply additional predicates.  But in general if you want users to slice-and-dice a the results of a complicated transformation, you should load it into a table and make it a "Data Mart".

Answer (score 0):

If the logical reads is the concern i would normally start to filter base tables (as mentioned by David Browne). In your case, it would go as function instead of view by applying `WHERE` clause inside CTE.

Also, I would suggest to avoid self join instead use `LEAD()` function, following is the same example that you can start with:

```
Declare @PersonID varchar(20) = 'YourData';

with timeline
as
(
    select person, location, dateTime, d_base
    from att.view_pD1
    where   person = @PersonID

    union all

    select  person, location, dateTime_in, d_base
    from    att.view_rule
    where   person = @PersonID

    union all

    select person, location, dateTime_out, d_base
    from att.view_rule
    where   person = @PersonID
)

select  person,
        location, 
        d_base,
        dateTime as StartTime,
        LEAD(dateTime) over (partition by person, location, d_base order by dateTime) EndTime
from    timeline
go
```

or To get extreme start and end date, you may start with following:

```
Declare @PersonID varchar(20) = 'YourData';

select  m.person, 
        m.location, 
        m.d_base, 
        s.datetime as StartTime, 
        e.datetime as EndTime
from att.<viewMasterData> as M

    LEFT JOIN 
    (select person, location, datetime, d_base,
            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (Partition by person, location, d_base order by datetime) as StartRN
    from    att.view_rule
    where   person = @PersonID
    ) as s ON M.person = s.person and m.location = s.location and m.base = s.base

    LEFT JOIN 
    (select person, location, datetime, d_base,
            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (Partition by person, location, d_base order by datetime desc) as EndRN
    from    att.view_rule
    where   person = @PersonID
    ) as e ON M.person = e.person and m.location = e.location and m.base = e.base
where s.StartRN = 1 and e.EndRN = 1
```